# Is it possible to rename a column in a view?

Tags: mysql, view

I'm not seeing much regarding this after some searching

Do I need to drop the view and recreate it or is there a way to edit a column name?

I tried `ALTER VIEW tableName oldColumnName newColumnName`

But got a syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ALTER` keyword instead of `CREATE` but [the syntax is the same](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-view.html).

This means `ALTER VIEW` does the same as `CREATE VIEW` but drops the existing view first. You must specify the **complete** new query that defines the view.

Comment: Thanks, so are you saying that I will need to recreate the whole view again?

Comment: Thanks, do you know of any reference to confirm this? Let me know, if not I will mark as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Yes, the link I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use :

```
CREATE VIEW viewname AS
SELECT colname "newcolname", colname "newcolname" FROM table-name;
```

its like give alias name to col of view..

Answer (score 1):

for me following code worked fine to rename a column

```
ALTER 
  ALGORITHM=MERGE
VIEW viewname AS
  SELECT emp_id as employee_id,first_name 
  FROM employee;
```

PS: it is for folks who tried `rename column col1 to col2` and other ways.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to move **column_name** *after* **another_column_name**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
MODIFY column_name datatype AFTER another_column_name;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
MODIFY column_name datatype BEFORE another_column_name;
```

to move **column_name** *before* **another_column_name**